# Mock a I-V characteristic of a solar cell?

Tags: power-supply, solar-cell

Is it possible to create a mock up of a power supply that would mimic an I-V graph of a solar cell?

The graph below shows what I'd like to achieve. Once the load tries to pull more than 200uA the voltage should start decreasing drastically.

[image]

I have the following components available:

- battery
- resistors
- capacitors
- inductors
- different types of diode and transisotrs
- op amps

Comment: Yes it is possible. But it would be cheaper to use a solar cell. If I had to do it, I would use a micro-controller to monitor voltage and current to stay on the VI curve.

Comment: A clue is to make a lousy current source with 2 transistors and 2 resistors and 1 cap.   cost $1 not including PSU. WHAT ARE your Voc, Isc specs?

Comment: @TonyStewart Voc (3-5V) Isc ( 1-10mA)

Comment: I didn't realize it was such a small cell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have specified two data points only, so I'm assuming that these are the only two parameters you want to vary.
Start with a basic diode, since the curve follows that of a diode. In the schematic below, the diode is D1. Its forward voltage defines Voc.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGvwAX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>
The short-circuit current is simulated with two PNP transistors, forming a current source that feeds the diode. With no load, diode D1 consumes all the current, generating an open-circuit voltage of Voc. A load of zero ohms (short circuit) diverts all the current from the current source, producing a load current of Isc.
In this example schematic, Isc is determined by the value of R1: Isc~0.64/R1
Out of Q1's collector, about 6.4 mA flows. Isc=6.5mA. Solar cell output terminals are labelled "Out +" and "Out -".
While crude, this could be a starting point to develop a more accurate model.
For a 5v cell, with short-circuit current of 217uA, this more versatile model allows piece-wise curve fitting by adjusting resistors R3-R11. As before, short circuit current is set by adjusting R1:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpYHcg.png)</sup>

Comment: Almost works, Voc cannot exceed 0.7.  what if Voc was 20V? and Isc was 10A

Comment: If Voc is 20v, then its a series-string of cells - a similar series string of diodes would replace the single D1 shown in the schematic. V1 would also have to scale up above 25v. For Isc of 10A, the current source would require a large Q1 on a heat sink.

Comment: In my case you only change V+ and Rb, Re with heatsink , natch.  Vbe moves towards 0.6.  It simulates any PV except uF is unknown. not hFE sensitive

Comment: I've updated the question with more details. I tried your circuit but couldn't get to these values. I've used transistors with 100hfe which is the minimal range for the one you've suggested.

Comment: @Alan With R1=2.2K or 2.7K, and R2=10K, should get you in the ballpark for Isc of about 250uA. To get up at 4.5 v, you'd need a series string of about seven silicon diodes to replace D1, and a DC supply greater than 6v. Tony's circuit is certainly more diode-conservative, and can be adjusted more precisely to get Voc.

Comment: Great, managed to do it, thanks. Was trying with the potentiometers before but couldn't find the spot :).
If you could elaborate on how R1, R2 and hfe influence the maximums and minimums of the mocked supply, will grant you the bounty.

Comment: @Alan, Current delivered current (I short-circuit) is set by base-emitter junction of Q2 (about 0.64v) divided by R1. Be aware that there's a temperature-dependence here. R2 is not terribly critical - can be at least 10X R1. In this ballpark, hfe has minor influence.

Comment: Was aiming for the actual function that would plot the I-V graph, but it seems honest to ask that as a separate question.

Comment: @Alan, A LTspice simulation with ten series diodes (1N4148) provides a fairly sharp "knee". It can be softened by adding resistor(s) to ground. With so many diodes, a piece-wise fit is possible to almost any curve. But it gets a little tricky to calculate resistor values, and where in the diode string to tap into. Am editing my answer with updated schematic...

Comment: @glen_geek D1. forward voltage IS NOT Voc. PV is a current source like reverse biased PD but with a PIV limit which is Voc.

Answer (score 2):

[PV Simulator](http://www.falstad.com/circuit-java/#%24+0+5.0E-6+20.712724888983452+58+10.0+50%0At+336+216+368+216+0+1+-0.8105150849688174+0.6246620886462138+50.0%0Ar+368+264+368+312+0+49.0%0Ag+224+344+304+344+0%0Aw+368+200+368+184+1%0Aw+368+152+368+184+0%0AR+160+328+128+328+0+3+44.0+0.005+0.632+0.0+0.5%0Aw+368+152+304+152+0%0Aw+304+312+368+312+0%0Ar+192+328+160+328+0+50.0%0Ar+304+200+304+152+0+100000.0%0At+368+264+336+264+0+1+-1.1510285364739694+0.3480871038532216+100.0%0At+304+200+336+200+0+1+-0.28414863714106176+0.5263664478277557+50.0%0Aw+304+312+304+280+2%0Aw+368+264+368+232+0%0Aw+336+248+304+248+0%0Aw+304+248+304+200+0%0Aw+368+184+336+184+0%0AR+368+152+368+104+0+0+40.0+5.8+0.0+0.0+0.5%0At+192+328+224+328+0+1+-3.391824487450773+0.6249112350809743+100.0%0Aw+224+312+304+312+1%0Aw+336+280+304+280+0%0Ax+163+437+478+443+0+24+PV+simulator10mA+5V+33+mW%0Ax+17+438+129+441+0+12+T.+Stewart+9%2F30%2F2016%0Ax+416+297+559+303+0+24+Isc+%3D+0.5V%2FRe%0Ax+404+137+541+143+0+24+Voc+%2B0.8%3DV%2B%0Ax+115+367+226+370+0+12+active+load+VI+sweep%0Ao+18+64+6+99+8.749002899132048+0.01093625362391506+0+-1+V-I%0Ao+19+64+0+34+4.676805239458889+0.005846006549323612+1+-1+Vs%0Ao+19+64+0+289+2.5+0.0125+2+-1+Is%0A)

[image]

- Active load sweep on left
- Precision PV simulator on right.
- VI curve on bottom left
- Isc=10.0mA
- Voc=5.0V
- Change Re for current range

Answer (score 0):

[image]

extrapolating to 10% or 100W/m^2 to 1000W/m^2
The load line is 16.5V to 17.5V. Thus the ideal load is a Constant Voltage Sink (CV) with a ESR to follow the load line for  1V rise to 17.5V @ 40W in this case or a rise in 40Wto 2W = 1V/2.2A = **ΔV/ΔI = ESR = 0.45 Ω**

**The ideal MP active load is not a constant current(CC) sink.**  But a lossy CC sink might work that has  current rising with Vin, such as my previous answer. This is due to the load line of Rbias/Rsense ratio with low loop gain.